# conditional http get request in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, get, mean-stack

I am trying to create a search box where the user types the singer's name in it and gets back his/her top hits from monogoDB.

I tried doing so using the below code however it does not work

```
router.get("/:singerName", function(req, res, next) {
  var singerName = req.params.singerName;
  Hit.find({ singerName: singerName }, function(err, hits) {
    if (err) {
      return res.render("/", { hits: null });
    }
    res.render("/", { hits: hits });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Marwa, what error you are facing? First confirm you are getting value of parameter by console.log(singerName) and check you have record by using robomongo or any other tool.
If fine then get variable value on page via `{{ hits }}` .